# Store data into out parameter cursor in procedure

Tags: java, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

I want to use a cursor in a procedure as an out parameter but, when I execute in java, the cursor returns me null

This is my procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OBTENER_ESTADO (RESULTADO OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
CURSOR RESULTADO
IS SELECT ID, NOMBRE FROM ESTADOS;
CLOSE RESULTADO;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
NULL;
END OBTENER_ESTADO;
```

this is my java code

```
public List<EstadosMexico> procedimientoEstados(Connection conn){
    List<EstadosMexico> le = null;
    try{
        CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{ CALL OBTENER_ESTADO(?)}");
        cs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        cs.executeUpdate();
        ResultSet cursor = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(1);
        cs.close();
        le = new ArrayList();
        while(cursor.next()) {
            le.add(new EstadosMexico(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getInt(2)));
        }
        cursor.close();
    } catch(SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getSQLState() + " " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return le;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the way to use `SYS_REFCURSOR` as `OUT` parameter of a Procedure. The way you are doing is not syntactically correct.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OBTENER_ESTADO (RESULTADO OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
   OPEN RESULTADO FOR 
   SELECT ID, NOMBRE FROM ESTADOS;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      NULL;
END OBTENER_ESTADO;
```